# Should custom meta boxes be able to output shortcodes the same as Wordpress' native post editor?

Tags: custom-field, metabox, shortcode

Simply put: Should custom meta boxes be able to output shortcodes the same way as Wordpress' native post editor?

Reason I ask is because Ive created my own custom meta box for inputting a shortcode from the Cart66 plugin in order to output an "Add To Cart" button but when I try - it only prints the text from the shortcode rather than rendering the actual button.

My current meta box:

```
<?php
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Register Custom Post Type Meta Box -- Add To Cart Button Field   //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'store_button_meta_box_add' );
function store_button_meta_box_add()
{
    add_meta_box( 'epr_store_button_meta_id', 'Add To Cart Button [shortcode]', 'store_button_meta_box_cb', 'epr_store', 'side', 'high' );
}

function store_button_meta_box_cb( $post )
{
    $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    $button = isset( $values['meta_box_button_shortcode'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['meta_box_button_shortcode'][0] ) : '';
    wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );
    ?>
    <p>
        <textarea name="meta_box_button_shortcode" id="meta_box_button_shortcode" row="5" style="width:100%; height:100px;text-align:left;"><?php echo esc_textarea($button); ?></textarea>
    </p>
    <?php   
}


add_action( 'save_post', 'epr_button_meta_box_save' );
function epr_button_meta_box_save( $post_id )
{
    // Bail if we're doing an auto save
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    // if our nonce isn't there, or we can't verify it, bail
    if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;

    // if our current user can't edit this post, bail
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

    // now we can actually save the data
    $allowed = array( 
        'a' => array( // on allow a tags
            'href' => array() // and those anchords can only have href attribute
        )
    );

    // Probably a good idea to make sure your data is set
    if( isset( $_POST['meta_box_button_shortcode'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_box_button_shortcode', wp_kses( $_POST['meta_box_button_shortcode'], $allowed ) );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **no**.

Shortcodes are for injecting content *directly in the Post Content*, by the *user*, via the Post Edit screen.

If your data are coming from a metabox, you have other, better, more efficient, and easier-to-control means of injecting content into the Post Content: primarily, the `the_content` filter (for general usage), or custom action hooks (for Themes that provide them).

Using the `the_content` filter to add your code is simple:

```
function my_plugin_filter_the_content( $content ) {
    // Get post custom meta
    $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    // Determine if shortcode meta is set
    $my_custom_content = isset( $values['meta_box_button_shortcode'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['meta_box_button_shortcode'][0] ) : '';
    // Tell WordPress to execute the shortcode
    $custom_shortcode_output = do_shortcode( $my_custom_content );
    // Append the executed shortcode to $content
    $content .= $custom_shortcode_output;
    // Return modified $content
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_plugin_filter_the_content' );
```

No need for a shortcode.

Also, using a filter, you don't have to worry about your shortcode being left orphaned if the user deactivates your Plugin.

**Note that, if you need to output a specific shortcode, you can use [`do_shortcode( '[shortcode_name att="value"]' )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode)**

Comment: Interesting...I wouldnt really know how to hook into each product id though that cart66 provides as individual shortcodes from a dropdown menu in the editor however.

Comment: You would query your custom post meta, of course - just like you're (presumably) doing now.

Comment: See updated answer. I think you need to use `do_shortcode()`, in addition to my previous answer.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response, been a busy day...Thanks for the help Chip, will this still be applicable even if each shortcodes values differ from one another, I havent tried it yet but it appears that the code is only trying to output 1 specific shortcode button each time which will not work if thats the case. --- In retrospect, I suppose what would be even more useful would be hooking directly into cart66's dropdown menu that the plugin generates and somehow placing it into a meta box. That would be ideal anyways, just wasnt sure if that would even be possible.

Comment: This method should work, if you know the name of the post custom meta key to query. You query it (via `get_post_custom()`), and then use its output (if set), to pass as the shortcode string to `do_shortcode()`. So, it looks to me like it should work.

Comment: Thanks Chip, are you referring to whatever "post meta key" is being used by Cart66 to instantiate the modular popup? Or are you saying your original proposed method should work for my needs. Further, would I need to obtain this meta key somewhere in Cart66's files, or would I be able to get it via firebug?